# Timer Interrupt in intel edison

Tags: iot, intel-edison

I have been trying to use Intel Edison with a Pulse sensor (http://pulsesensor.com/products/pulse-sensor-amped). 
I have seen examples of the same with Arduino Uno. 
It uses a timer function for Arduino using Atmega328 and 16MHz clock. The specs for the edison are different. So what will be the changes for my intel edison. Kindly guide.

The code for Arduino Uno that deals with the interrupt part is:

```
void interruptSetup(){ 
  TCCR2A = 0x02;  
  TCCR2B = 0x06; 
  OCR2A = 0x7C;  
  TIMSK2 = 0x02;  
  sei();
}
```

This gives an interrupt in every 2ms.

Comment: What have you tried already? Obviously the registers will be different, and there's a whole procedure for figuring out the correct settings on your specific platform. Instead of asking how to port Arduino code to an Edison, shouldn't you just focus on asking how to get the Pulse sensor to work on Edison in general?

Comment: I have figured out quite a few things about the pulse sensor, I am able to get the raw pulse sensor values using the intel edison on my laptop (serially). So no, my question is apt. I believe I should be looking at some Linux options to work the timer interrupt out in intel edison. So, if its not too much trouble would you let me know if my direction is correct or should I be looking at something else?